# i want to retrieve every count specific data in a field

Tags: vb.net

is there any way to do this ? i want to retrieve every count of data in a field

here's my code..

```
 Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(support) AS support " & _
                            "FROM   Studz_Table WHERE support ='others'",conn)
dim int1 as integer = cmd1.executescalar

Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(support) AS support " & _
                            "FROM   Studz_Table WHERE support ='myself'",conn)
dim int2 as integer = cmd1.executescalar
Dim cmd3 As New SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(support) AS support " & _
                            "FROM   Studz_Table WHERE support ='parent'",conn)
dim int3 as integer = cmd1.executescalar
```

is there any simple way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of SUM and CASE to retrieve counts for each type.

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN support = 'others' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OthersCount, " & _
                          "SUM(CASE WHEN support = 'myself' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MyselfCount, " & _
                          "SUM(CASE WHEN support = 'parent' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ParentCount " & _
                            "FROM   Studz_Table WHERE support ='others'",conn)
```

You'll need to use `ExecuteReader` though instead of `ExecuteScalar` to access each column:

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
     int int1 = reader[0];
     int int2 = reader[1];
     int int3 = reader[2];
}
```

Comment: hmmm..another thing..can we use loop in UPDATE in sql ?

Comment: @user3211476: Your second question looks like a different one, please take your time to accept the above as an answer first. Then ask a separate question. Thanks.

Comment: hmmm..how to accept the answer ? uhmm..i mean..where's the button to accept the answer to make this question as a resolved..?

Comment: @user3211476 - Click the tick on the left of the answer to turn it green and mark it as accepted. You can also optionally click the up arrow if you consider the answer helpful.